# How can I jump to the source code from 'Send actions' in Connections Inspector in XCode?

Tags: xcode, xcode15

How can I jump to the source code from 'Send actions' in Connections Inspector in XCode?
I tried all possible mouse click combined with modifer keys but still not work.
[image]

Comment: You can't. "Jumping" works only the other way.

Comment: @matt ok...What's the quickest way to locate to that method? cmd+shif+o and search for that metho?